# Is the digital declaration just an obscure proposal?

Tags: authentication, digital-signature, integrity

One professor from my university proposed me and some colleagues to work on a paper about the digital declaration (which is supposed to be better than the digital signature) for passing the subject. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be a well known concept. One of the colleagues has done a search and she has only sent me the links of a few papers written by a professor from Switzerland called Ueli Maurer. And I haven't found a digital-declaration tag here on the website.

Still, is anybody more familiar with the digital declaration and could suggest us a few papers or something?

Comment: Surely your professor is the best source for further information? Or is this an assignment for you to figure out on your own without their help?

Comment: well, I can ask my professor a few questions, but I believe it is our task as students to do the reading and then writing

Comment: Since this question is the #4 result on a Google search only 9 hours after it was posted, I'm going to go out on a limb and say it's either mostly an obscure proposal or perhaps it's very peculiar jargon for a more common concept.  [Maurer has a patent on it](http://www.google.com/patents/US20040139344) and Alin Golumbeanu appears to have written a bit on it as well.  There's also a more interesting reference in "Isse 2005 -Securing Electronic Business Processes: Highlights of the Information Security Solutions Europe 2005 Conference", a $64 book, in a section on time stamps.  It's ambiguous.